# Is typeorm querybuilder select, orderBy, groupBy are SQL injection safe?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, sql-injection

If TypeORM query builder select, orderBy, and groupBy are not SQL injection safe, How to convert them into SQL injection safe?

```
qb.orderBy(
      `incident.${query.sortColum}`,
      query.sortOrder === 'desc' ? DESCENDING : ASCENDING,
    );

qb.select([
  `incident.${query.type}`,
  `COUNT('') As "count"`,
  `"incident"."locationGroupIds"[${level}] as groupId`,
]);

qb.addGroupBy(`incident.${query.type}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

These elements cannot be bound into JDBC which is why TypeORM doesn't support them as parameterized queries.

There are two options to do this safely - ideally you should use both:

- Validate the columns in these via positive / whitelist validation. Each column name should be checked for existence in the associated tables.
- You should enquote the column name - adding single quotes around the columns. If you do this, you need to be careful to validate there are no quotes in the name, and error out or escape any quotes. You also need to be aware that adding quotes will make the name case sensitive.